# Kylin implementation

Tags: architecture, implementation, kylin

I'm planning to do a poc on kylin at my company. I went through the apache documentation and I have couple of questions regarding installation and overall architecture.

1. Can I have kylin(job/query) engine on one emr cluster, hadoop/hive (source or data processing) on a different emr cluster and finally a stand alone emr cluster for Hbase ? If yes, what are the config files that I need to update to connect all three and are there any examples or documentation that I can follow for this kind of setup?

The documentation by apache for stand alone hbase cluster was no clear enough it doesn't have how we can connect hadoop cluster with kylin cluster.

Comment: Dear friend, did you ever faced problem in deploy a Read/Write separated Kylin  deployment? Have you ever tried to check this article http://kylin.apache.org/blog/2016/06/10/standalone-hbase-cluster/ ?

If you still faced any specific issue, please attach your `kylin.properties`, `kylin.log` or other information which can help me to know what happen in your env, I think someone might check it carefully in that case.

Comment: Did you mean Kylin website should update [http://kylin.apache.org/docs/install/kylin_aws_emr.html] and add some step to introduce steps of a Read/Write separated Kylin deployment?